# Android Layout Inspector too smart

Tags: android, layout

I want to Inspect Notification, and I need run my test app to send notification, so my app is running when connect layout inspector.

Bui the Layout inspect too smart, if my app is running, it always connect to my app instead of show a menu to select systemui process.

How can I make this case work? I try disable debuggable in gradle but it won't work either.

We do not need such smart design.